# Find bijective correspondence between the sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Find bijective correspondence between the set of all functions of $X$
>   in the set $\left\{ 0,1 \right\}$ and the power set of set $X$ and
>   find $| 2 ^ X |$, if $| X | = n.$

---

**My thoughts**: number of functions between set $X$ and $\left\{ 0,1 \right\}$ = $2 ^ n$, because $| X | = n$. Power of power set is $| 2 ^ X | = 2 ^ n$. Therefore, between the two sets can be bijection. It remains to figure out now how to do it to each element of the power set put in correspondence exactly one function of $X$ into $\left\{ 0,1 \right\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a particular function $f:X\to\{0,1\}$, let $S$ be the preimage of $1$. In other words,

$$S=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=1\}$$

This is your desired bijection.

For the inverse bijection, given a subset $S\subseteq X$, define $f:X\to\{0,1\}$ by

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x\not\in S$} \\
1,  & \text{if $x\in S$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: You have a missing word or two which makes your answer difficult to understand

Comment: @GFauxPas what are they?

Comment: I don't know what's missing. "The is your desired bijection" is what I'm referring to.

Comment: @GFauxPas: I meant "*This* is your desired bijection." It is now corrected. Thanks for mentioning the problem!